# ruby block that starts with <<-HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm learning about integrating Devise flash and error messages with Bootstrap (or in my case Materialize).  I found an article on the topic within Devise's wiki (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Integrate-I18n-Flash-Messages-with-Devise-and-Bootstrap), so I understand how it has to work, but there was a section of the code I'm having problems understanding.

```
html = <<-HTML
<div class="card-panel red lighten-2"> 
  #{messages}
</div>
HTML

html.html_safe
```

Can someone explain the `<<-HTML` syntax?   BTW, here is the full function in case you need context

```
def devise_error_messages!
return '' if resource.errors.empty?

messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
html = <<-HTML
<div class="card-panel red lighten-2"> 
  #{messages}
</div>
HTML

html.html_safe
end
```

Comment: It is called the `here doc` : http://log.gmarik.info/2007/12/rubys-here-document-heredoc-mini.html

Comment: BTW, you can call a method on a heredoc: `<<-HTML.html_safe`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a <del>ruby</del> common way to declare a string, it is pretty useful in some cases (edit: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document thanks to @Stefan):

```
sql = <<-SQL
  SELECT * FROM users
  WHERE users.id > 15
  ORDER BY users.username;
SQL
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Way better to read this than a simple:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.id > 15 ORDER BY users.username;"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Imagine the pain to read a very complex SQL query without any line-break! (like with a manual join, recursive, union or views of table(s)!

---

It works with any kind of word:

```
a_string = <<-WHATEVER
  This is a string
  with some line-break
  to make it more readable
  #{and_you_can_use_string_interpolation_too}
WHATEVER
```

Comment: Not just a Ruby way, [heredocs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) exist in various languages.

Comment: I know ruby is pretty smart when it comes to line breaks, but you're saying that since it's a String it will take it explicitly.  So in your example, the server would not accept `sql = "SELECT * FROM \n WHERE \n...`? into `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)?

Comment: Yes it would because the line-breakers `"\n"` won't be used in the SQL query. (copy-paste the example in your IRB console, it works)

Comment: I understand what you're saying, I just wanted to know if it was just for human readability, or if the argument would work if put line breaks into the single line sql variable.  I get what you're saying though.  I can try it myself.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is for human readability. The SQL query code I used returns `"  SELECT * FROM users\n  WHERE users.id > 15\n  ORDER BY users.username;\n"` and the `"\n"` are not treated in the SQL query